# How do I fetch from swapi from react app?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to call the [Star Wars Api (swapi)](https://swapi.dev/) from a react app with this code:

```
export function getAsync(route: string, baseUrl: string) {
  // var url = baseUrl + "/" + route;
  let url = "http://swapi.dev/api/planets?page=1";
  let status: number;

  return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response: any) => {
      status = response.status;
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
   //more stuff
}
```

However I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://swapi.dev/api/planets?page=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not 
allowed for a preflight request.
```

What do I need to do to modify my fetch request? I notice that examples of connecting to this API used swapi.co but it's since changed to swapi.dev.

Comment: Also it may have to be HTTPS

Comment: The [base url](https://swapi.dev/documentation#base) is `https://swapi.dev/api/`. Try `https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=1`.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the docs, it seems the url should be like so:

> http://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=1

instead of:

> http://swapi.dev/api/planets?page=1

Answer (score 0):

> The browser deems the request to be a "simple" request when the
> request itself meets a certain set of requirements:
>
> When using the Content-Type header, only the following values are
> allowed: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
> text/plain

[Source](https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing)

So I can't use `"content-type": "application/json"` . Actually I think that content-type is supposed to be used for when  you are sending data up from client to server. We are generally not doing that for a simple GET request.

So I should write:

```
 return fetch(url, {
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/")
    .then((res) => setShips(res.data.results));
  }, [])
```